# Debugging problem in VB.Net with Windows Forms with losing events

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events

We have a huge application that runs through a mass of code for every click you do. In one specific case, where you have a specific control in plain sight (so that the events are firing) and you load some special data into it and then click on the new button the form loses some events, like the closing event (you cannot close the form anymore and stop points in debug mode are not triggered) and one validating of a `ComboBox` that is really needed for the program. The only thing you can do when you get this kind of error is to restart the application to get out of this subform. But I tested it for 2 days now and even when I activate all points in the 'Exception Settings' I don't get any exceptions. The form (and other controls) are not losing ALL events. The resize, for example, still works. Even a specifically called `AddHandler` is not firing. Can you iterate somehow through the EventHandlerList? Or is there any way to test WHERE the event dies? Somehow any ideas on how to debug such a problem?

Comment: A sample code, showing how/when these events are created/referenced, is clearly needed. It would be useful to know how the data in the `ComboBox` you're referring to is loaded. Also, are you using `Application.DoEvents()` somewhere? Events don't usually desappear. More probably are never subscribed to, for some reason. Or removed and never added gaing. Or an error prevents the execution/doesn't give a chance to execute. Or the UI thread is blocked/stuck beacause of some recursion or another thread which silently died.

Comment: Sample code is problematic, because there are nearly 10k lines of code in this form and the referenced classes. The `ComboBox` uses a `DataBinding` to a `DataSet`. The complete UI is not stuck, because it still reacts and events like the resize are still firing. I guess that an error prevents the execution, but how to find this? Can `Application.DoEvents()`help somehow? I didn't used it till now anywhere.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` won't help, the opposite. I asked because it could be a possible cause of the problem. You'll need to debug the code and see if, at some point, the execution *jumps* for apparently no reason. Anyway, at least specify whether these events are dinamically created somewhere or part ot the `InitializeComponent()` proc (set through the Designer). Are you using some form of concurrent threading to update the UI, load the data (or anywhere else)?

Comment: Oh, I see that this `Application.DoEvents()` is really called at one time... hm... I will look into it and get back here as soon as I have found out if this is the problem.

Comment: Ok, I commented the only part where `Application.DoEvents()` was out, but the error still occurs. The events are created at `InitializeComponents()` and we have nearly no async code. There are some updates to the form and the bindings for all the objects, but everything in the same thread. Or did you mean something else with concurrent?

Comment: *nearly no async code* means no other threads/tasks or some? If the latter, can you post a sample code of a thread init/async method/BackgroundWorker, specifing why/where/when it's used?

Comment: No, we only use one `AsyncDataFilledEventArgs` and the corresponding `IAsyncResult`, etc. So only the data that comes from the database ist async, the rest is sync code.

Comment: I don't know what `AsyncDataFilledEventArgs` is. But, apparently, you have some CallBack that returns a Data retrieval completion event. Without the chance to see any code related to threading and/or event handling, it's hard to say something meningful.

Comment: "you load ... data into it and then click on the new button the form loses some events, like the closing event (you cannot close the form anymore...) and one validating of a ComboBox"  - Are you using the `ComboBox.Validating` event? If so look at that code to ensure that the data you load does not cause the validation to fail.   With standard validation, invalid data will prevent closing the containing form. The form can be closed with invalid data, but it requires handling the FormClosing event and setting the FormClosingEventArgs argument's Cancel property to False.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks. That it was. I seem to have a problem with the `DataBinding` therefore the e.Cancel was `true` in the `me.Closing` on the Form.